# Read all Emails with flag not set as "Mark Complete" only using EWS

Tags: exchangewebservices

I'm trying to read all the unread emails which are not marked as "Mark Complete" flag. I used below code to read email:

SearchFilter ReadFilter = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And, new SearchFilter.Not(new SearchFilter.Exists(new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(0x1090, MapiPropertyType.Integer))));

But this is not returning emails whose flag is set by sender as "Today".

I'm using flag "Mark Complete" once my autosys job reads email and processes. So it is important to check if the email has "Mark Complete" before processing. But the above code is not fetching any email with flag set.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use the pidTagTaksStatus property instead https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/pidlidtaskstatus-canonical-property and then construct your filter like

```
        ExtendedPropertyDefinition pidTagTaskStatus = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(DefaultExtendedPropertySet.Task, 0x8101, MapiPropertyType.Integer);
        SearchFilter SetComplete = new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(pidTagTaskStatus, 2);
        SearchFilter sfCol = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And)
        {
            new SearchFilter.Not(SetComplete)
        };
```

So it should find anything that's flagged but not set to complete

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  But the code is not fetching the emails if it is not flagged.  My criteria is to 1. fetch all emails which are not marked as complete 2. Fetch emails which have any follow up flag is set(Not Mark Complete).  Both these conditions need to be met.  Even though "Mark Complete" is under Follow up flag.  I want to retrieve all the emails with the above two conditions.  Once the email is processed, it will be marked as "Mark complete" by my job.

Comment: All you need to do is just remove the propexists filter in that case and it should work I've modified the code in the answer

Comment: When the propexists filter is removed, it is fetching the emails which are Marked complete.  Once they are marked complete, job shouldn't fetch and process them.  What does 0X8101 or 0x1090 means?

Comment: And it is also fetching the emails which are already flagged as "Mark Complete".

Comment: My code is working now, except that the email which has flag "Followup\Add Reminder \Flag for Recipents" is set I am able to fetch that email, process and add "Mark Complete" flag.  But this email even though it is Mark Complete it is again getting processed.    I'm using below code to Mark Complete flag       ExtendedPropertyDefinition epd_pidTagFlagStatus = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(0x1090, MapiPropertyType.Integer);   iEM.SetExtendedProperty(epd_pidTagFlagStatus, 0x00000001);  iEM.update(ConflictResoultionMode.AutoResolve);

Comment: As the above code with EPD 0x1090 and Mark Complete flag is set, I think when 0x8101 is used to check the MarkComplete it is not working.

Comment: code:SearchFilter NotMarkCompleteFilter = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And, new SearchFilter.Not(new SearchFilter.Exists(new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(0x1090, MapiPropertyType.Integer))));
ExtendedPropertyDefinition pidTagTaskStatus = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(DefaultExtendedPropertySet.Task, 0x8101, MapiPropertyType.Integer);
        SearchFilter propExists = new SearchFilter.Exists(pidTagTaskStatus);
        SearchFilter sfCol = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.or)
        {
            propExists, NotMarkCompleteFilter
        };

Comment: How to check the Mark Complete flag for email which has which has flag "Followup\Add Reminder \Flag for Recipents" ?